# Why is div within span illegal?

Tags: html

It is not legal to have <div> elements within a <span> element. But if I understand it correctly, a <span> can be made to work like a <div> and vice versa by setting the CSS 'display' property to 'block' or 'inline'.

If it is that easy to bypass the containment rules, what is the point of having them?

Comment: HTML predates CSS. It was not so easy to bypass containment rules back then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's illegal to have a div in a span because div is a bloc element, span is an inline element.
It's not related to rendering (CSS display) but on semantic.
Ask yourself, does it make sense to have a h1 inside a span ?

Comment: Thank you, kbdjockey (and RB with a similar answer).

Answer (score 2):

The issue is one  of semantics. A [Span element](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/text-level-semantics.html#the-span-element) is expected to include [Phrasing Content](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#phrasing-content-1) - i.e. the text of the document.

A [Div](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/grouping-content.html#the-div-element) element is not phrasing content. It is for logical divisions of content.